# groovy in build.gradle file - how to swap closures/methods

Tags: groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Looking for  a groovy expert to assist me.  In my android build.gradle file i have

the following defined:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply from: 'other.gradle'//this contains another flavor


//A method to detect if another gradle build file is available
def boolean isOtherBuildFile() {
     return new File('other.gradle').exists()
    }


    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

        defaultConfig {
            //blah blah not important
        }

        buildTypes {
            debug {
                //blah blah not important
            }

            release {
              //blah blah not important

            }
        }

            productFlavors {
                def STRING = "String"
                def BOOLEAN = "boolean"
//i'd like to be able to swap out this mock closure below with another one
                mock {
                    applicationId "org.example.mock"
                    versionName = "1.5" + '-mock'
                    buildConfigField STRING, GCM_SENDER_ID, '"123456789"'
                    buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"localhost/"'
                }
              }
```

in the file called other.gradle i want to redefine mock to be something else.  for example in other.gradle i could have mock defined like this:

```
 mock {
           applicationId "com.tutorial.mock"
           versionName = "2.4" + '-mock'
           buildConfigField STRING, GCM_SENDER_ID, '"987654321"'
           buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"www.mymockdomain.com/"'
            }
```

so here is what i want to accomplish: i'd like to be check in puesdo code, the following:

```
if(isOtherBuildFile())
then
    //use the mock defined in other.gradle

else 
   //continue to use the mock defined in build.gradle
```

it is in android studio but i dont think it being android has anything to do with groovy syntax i hope. im also ok with swapping out the entire flavor closure as thats a even better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough to:

```
if(isOtherBuildFile() {
   project.apply: 'other.gradle'
} else {
   mock {}
}
```

Have you already tried that?